# unable to resize components in java windowbuilder

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, windowbuilder

I'm designing GUI using java swing with the help of `windowbuilder`. I found that in any layout it's not possible to resize components by using mouse drags (even though it shows points to pick and drag to resize). Specifically reducing size is what most important to do.

Resizing is allowed only in two layouts: one in `Absolute Layout` (which is not at all good for practical purpose, considering different screen-sizes with which GUI should be better displayed) and another is Group Layout (which is also not a good for design due to it's complex code).

Following is the sample where I have placed two `JLabel`s and now trying to add `JComboBox` at the location indicated by `Green` box.

[image]

But when I place the `JComboBox` it's default size is to `fill horizontally`. Even if I change `fill` to 'None' and try to resize, I'm unable to resize it. Following is the result after addition of `JComboBox`:

[image]

In the Background there is JPanel with GridBagLayout with following properties:

[image]

I found that changing values in `columnWidths` and `rowHeights` properties of `GridBagLayout`, the size of grid columns/rows can be controlled. But I'm unable to understand `Size of which columns/rows all those values represents?`. (I found no direct relation between number of those values and number of columns/rows displayed on Panel)

Is there any way out to resize components? And can anybody explain what those values in `columnWidths` and `rowHeights` properties of `GridBagLayout` represent?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, you need to add `grow` in you WindowBuilder. It looks like this:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpyzk.jpg)

Click on this with your right mouse button and click on 'grow':

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r9WH.jpg)

Only objects with 'grow' are resizable.